# HTML Emails: How to hide whitespace?

Tags: html, email, templates, fonts, whitespace

I'm building an email template. Part of the design involves using Georgia Italic as the font. The text only takes up the bottom 75% of the space allotted for the text. This means there's a sizable amount of whitespace above the text.

Here's the code:

```
<table width="660" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="420" height="200" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; font-size:300px; line-height:300px; color:#e47b5c; padding: 10px 0 10px 0; font-style:italic; line-height:300px; border-collapse:collapse;" >
                        <span>75</span>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right" valign="bottom" width="240" height="200" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; color:#e47b5c;" >
                        <table align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="middle" style="font-size:150px; line-height:150px; color:#e47b5c; font-style:italic;">
                                    <span>%</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" style="font-size:80px; line-height:80px; color:#e47b5c;">
                                    <span>OFF</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AEhy6/1/
(select the "75%" to see the extra space)

I'm looking for a way to cover up the whitespace.

I suspect the only way is to change the font. All ideas are welcome! Thank you.

Comment: reduce the `line-height`...

Comment: Has to do with the x-height of the font's numerals, I guess. I don't know if all desired mail platforms support negative top margin on i.e. a div, but you could look into that; same goes for line-height.

Comment: Thanks. I reduced the line-height and set valign="top". Works great.

Comment: @A.O maybe u can add this as an answer so that it can be marked as answered.

Comment: The text style Georgia Italic drops numbers down to the bottom of the line.  Is this example really showing your situation.  If you write multiple lines of text it looks funny with a shorter line-height.  Are you really just trying to change the height of numbers in their own cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you can reduce the `line-height` to get rid of the undesired whitespace present above the letters....

Comment: On the fiddle, this works down to 217px if I am not mistaken.